# Fully transparent reverse proxy

Tags: nginx, ssl, reverse-proxy, subdomain, transparent-proxy

I'm trying to set up the following:

```
┌──────────────────┐            ┌────────────────────┐           ┌─────────┐    
│                  │            │                    │           │         │    
│      Router      │            │                    │           │Server 1 │    
│       NAT        │Port forward│                    │           │         │    
│                  │ ────────►  │     Server 0       │           │HTTP >   │    
│                  │            │                    │           │HTTPS    │    
│                  │            │    1.example.com  ───────────► │redirect │    
│                  │            │    2.example.com  ────┐        └─────────┘    
└──────────────────┘            └────────────────────┘  │         192.168.178.8 
                                     192.168.178.4      │                       
                                                        │   ┌─────────┐         
                                                        │   │         │         
                                                        │   │         │         
                                                        │   │Server 2 │         
                                                        └─► │         │         
                                                            │HTTP only│         
                                                            │         │         
                                                            └─────────┘         
                                                            192.168.178.7
```

I want server 0 to act as a fully transparent proxy that only forwards the traffic. So that the clients don't establish TLS connection with server 0, but directly with server 1/2 and the HTTP-01 challenge based automated certificate generation and renewal on server 1/2 still works.

Comment: not sure, but would [this](https://caddyserver.com/docs/caddyfile/directives/reverse_proxy#transports) help at all?

Comment: That doesn't work. Server0 needs at least to do SNI to decide which server should handle the request. You need to terminate SSL at server0. (Or be able to decrypt the packets to forward them properly)

Comment: you may use squid and define 2 routes for that hosts

Comment: You can use nginx on Server0 with the stream TCP proxy module. nginx can parse the TLS SNI field from stream and pass the stream to a server based on SNI. https://serverfault.com/questions/1023756/nginx-stream-map-with-wildcard contains a configuration you can start with.

Comment: Why not run a TCP-loadbalancer?'

Comment: @Orphans At the time I wanted to Nginx, but I eventually switched to HAProxy

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Edit:
If you are concerned about the connection between your reverse proxy (that terminates the SSL tunnel) and the content server being unsecured, although this does work and is secure, you might be better off configuring upstream SSL or a secure tunnel like SSH or IPSEC between the content server and your reverse proxy.

---

I got it working:

File structure:

```
ngnix/
    config/
        nginx.conf
    http_server_name.js
    docker-compose.yml
```

nginx.conf

```json
load_module modules/ngx_stream_js_module.so;

events {}

stream {
    js_import main from http_server_name.js;
    js_set $preread_server_name main.get_server_name;

    map $preread_server_name $http {
        1.example.com server1_backend_http;
        2.example.com server2_backend_http;
    }

    map $ssl_preread_server_name $https {
        1.example.com server1_backend_https;
        2.example.com server2_backend_https;
    }

    upstream server1_backend_http {
        server 192.168.178.8:80;
    }
    
    upstream server1_backend_https {
        server 192.168.178.8:443;
    }

    upstream server2_backend_http {
        server 192.168.178.7:80;
    }

    server {
        listen 443;  
        ssl_preread on;
        proxy_pass $https;
    }

    server {
        listen 80;
        js_preread main.read_server_name;
        proxy_pass $http;
    }
}
```

docker-compose.yml

```yml
version: '3'

services:
  ngnix:
    image: nginx
    container_name: ngnix
    restart: unless-stopped
    volumes:
      - ./config/ngnix.conf:/etc/nginx/nginx.conf:ro
      - ./config/http_server_name.js:/etc/nginx/http_server_name.js:ro
    ports:
      - "192.168.178.4:80:80"
      - "192.168.178.4:443:443"
```

[http_server_name.js](https://serverfault.com/a/1045912/597211)

```js
var server_name = '-';

/**
 * Read the server name from the HTTP stream.
 *
 * @param s
 *   Stream.
 */
function read_server_name(s) {
  s.on('upload', function (data, flags) {
    if (data.length || flags.last) {
      s.done();
    }

    // If we can find the Host header.
    var n = data.indexOf('\r\nHost: ');
    if (n != -1) {
      // Determine the start of the Host header value and of the next header.
      var start_host = n + 8;
      var next_header = data.indexOf('\r\n', start_host);

      // Extract the Host header value.
      server_name = data.substr(start_host, next_header - start_host);

      // Remove the port if given.
      var port_start = server_name.indexOf(':');
      if (port_start != -1) {
        server_name = server_name.substr(0, port_start);
      }
    }
  });
}

function get_server_name(s) {
  return server_name;
}

export default {read_server_name, get_server_name}
```

Documentation:
[ngx_http_upstream_module](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_upstream_module.html)
[ngx_http_map_module](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_map_module.html)
[ngx_stream_proxy_module](http://nginx.org/en/docs/stream/ngx_stream_proxy_module.html)

Edit #1:
Read [this blog post](https://web.archive.org/web/20211018114557/https://www.alibabacloud.com/blog/how-to-use-nginx-as-an-https-forward-proxy-server_595799) for more info

Edit #2:
You can also use regex to have a default backend and exceptions for other domains or choose your backend dynamically based on parameters in the domain.
Read [this gist](https://web.archive.org/web/20221007144020/https://gist.github.com/kekru/c09dbab5e78bf76402966b13fa72b9d2) for more info